# Can a purchased open type font be used as a web font?

Tags: webfonts

I'm hoping to confirm that if I purchase an open type font from a foundry that I can then use it on the web by using the @font-face command.

Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, for more read [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/). But the client browsers need to support @font-face.